# C: Store parameter passed when calling main

Tags: c, string, variables

I would like to know how to store parameters in C when I compile:

For example: I'd like to store 2 user-input string variables.
The main is called like this:

```
./main "Hello World!" World
```

We should store "Hello World!" in `string1` and "World" in `string2` 
(supposing we can only use the main function and no head function), without using pointers.

edit: here is my code that still doesn't work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <err.h>

int  
main (int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    if (argc != 2)
    { 
    errx(1, "Error");
    }
    printf("Number of arguments = %i\n", argc);
    for (int k = 0; k < argc; k += 1)
        {
        printf("argv[%i] = %s\n", i, argv[i]);
        }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you post any code that you have tried? Or any error messages you get when you run your code?

Comment: I cannot test it since I cannot store the variables

Comment: Is it possible to do this without using pointers (at all)

Comment: Mr Bowling I have seen this but didn't understand how the two strings would be stored, how ?

Comment: You can't do this in C without using pointers. You'll need them to pass arguments from the command line and for the strings.

Comment: You can't copy a string without passing the name of the string, which is the address of the first character in the string, which is a pointer to a character.

Comment: I'm puzzled about what you mean by "store parameters in C when I compile".  The command line shown runs after the program is compiled and the strings passed as arguments are not available at compile time (and are not fixed at run time).  It is easy enough to capture the two arguments, usually simply by using the pointers to them. But you'd have to do some extraordinary work to get this information into the program at compile time (and it is not clear what benefit you'd get from doing so). Seeking to avoid pointers when playing with strings is like trying to swim without getting wet — not easy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the `main` declaration is `int main(int argc, char **argv);` or `int main(int argc, char *argv[]);`, where:

- `argc` is the number of arguments passed
- `**argv` or `*argv[]` contains the arguments to pass

So you have to use pointers to pass the arguments (as main is declared), there is no other way. In your example (`./main "Hello World!" World`), the program will receive:

- `argc` is 3
- `argv[0]` is ./main
- `argv[1]` is Hello World!
- `argv[2]` is World

Comment: Right, thanks. But somehow I get an error when printing... I do printf("argv[%i] = "%s", i, argv[i]") but it gives me an error

Comment: @quiasdesamis2: Apart from the fact you omitted the newline at the end of the format string, you have stray double quotes all over the place.  Consider using single quotes, or use `\"` for each `"` that you want to appear in the format string.  You need more like: `printf("argv[%i] = \"%s\"\n", i, argv[i]);` — note that this removes the trailing double quote shown in your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53377555/c-store-parameter-passed-when-calling-main#comment93632410_53378071) where it says: `printf("argv[%i] = "%s", i, argv[i]")`.

Comment: Try `printf("argv[%u] = %s\n", i, argv[i]);`, being i an unsigned in the range [0-2]

Comment: it still gives me 2 errors, located at > i and at >argv[i]

Comment: I have edited my question please take a look it doesn't compile